# How can I remove Ubuntu from the UEFI boot options? 2

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I'm using Dell Inspiron 11, 3000 Series
I uninstalled Ubuntu , but when I start my computer it gives me the message:

> Minimal BASH like line editing....

When I write `exit` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> it leads me to UEFI boot options including Ubuntu though already uninstalled.
I also can't install Ubuntu anymore. Please asist.

Comment: And what operating system are you using now?

Comment: If you still have Ubuntu live installer you can use efibootmgr. But you should just be able to go into UEFI and edit UEFI boot entries from there. Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: Right now Im using Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu you can use EFI boot manager.

```
sudo install efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

The boot order is the list, and if you want to delete ubuntu here, which is zero, just ask efibootmgr to remove it from the boot order.

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 4,2001,2002,2003
```

and if you want it back

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,4,2001,2002,2003
```

if you want to boot windows by default

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 4,0,2001,2002,2003
```

Edited: If you don't have access to ubuntu, try booting from a bootable Ubuntu via USB. Use the latest 18.04, it should have efibootmgr in the desktop live ISO.

Additional reading if you want to do this in windows, see microsoft documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-boot-options-in-efi

Comment: The -o option is just changing boot order, you want the -b option to delete entries. see `man efibootmgr` and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743

Comment: That's right, but -b option is to set default boot selection @oldfred, you meant to say  -B option to delete an entry.

Comment: As I said I uninstalled ubuntu and Im using windows now , I would like to install ubuntu again but I cant

Comment: Were you able to use the bios boot selection to boot from an Ubuntu installation USB?